# What type of tree is in this image?

Tags: identification, trees

[image: tree in South Florida, USA]

This is in South Florida. I was given these pictures and unfortunately do not have any close up of the leaves or bark. When it rains, this area floods.

Comment: Either a larch, Cypress or Juniper. Need a close-up pic. But I have my bets on Swamp Cypress.